# How can i call event celldoubleclick in Spreadjs by js code?

Tags: javascript

I have a spreadsheet and i set event celldoubleclick:

```js
activeSheet.bind(GcSpread.Sheets.Events.CellDoubleClick, function (sender, args) {
//TODO: do something
});
```

Now I want to call celldoubleclick event by javascript inside $( document ).ready(). Give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in our response.  This should be similar to the other answer posted here:

[Selenium driver for testing SpreadJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700072/selenium-driver-for-testing-spreadjs)

The only difference would be is that you would use action.DoubleClick() instead of action.Click().

Regards,
Spread Team